Gradlew dart-defines stopped working after gradles build refresh
I am passing few arguments to gradlew build in flutter to run integration_tests in local machine. It had been working good till now:
Firebase_set_base64=$(echo -n "set=firebase" | base64)
Test_Set_Base64=$(echo -n "test-set=$TEST_SET" | base64)

flutter build apk --debug --flavor rc
  ./gradlew app:assembleRcDebugAndroidTest
  ./gradlew app:connectedRcDebugAndroidTest -Ptarget=integration_test/main_test.dart \
      -Pdart-defines="$Firebase_set_base64,$Test_Set_Base64


I ran following command to upgrade/refresh gradle dependencies:
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies -x lint
Firebase_set_base64=$(echo "set=firebase"| base64) #Removed -n after error by `gradlew`
Test_Set_Base64=$(echo "test-set=$TEST_SET"| base64)

flutter build apk --debug --flavor rc
    ./gradlew app:assembleRcDebugAndroidTest
    ./gradlew app:connectedRcDebugAndroidTest -Ptarget=integration_test/main_test.dart -Pdart-defines="$Firebase_set_base64,$Test_Set_Base64

Now there is following error and the build is not running:

-Dset=firebase%0A: Error: Error when reading '-Dset=firebase%0A': No such file or directory Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

